# Use setTimeout after setState in react to avoid async issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I often do this

```
this.setState({
something: this.state.something + 1
})

setTimeout(() => { this.props.somefunction(this.state.something) },100);
```

Is this even correct? but this at least solved my problem. If I don't do timeout here `somefunction` which is declared in my parent component will received an undefined param. I guess doing `this.props.somefunction()` is executed before `setState` is done?

Comment: What's the purpose? Trying to guess when setState will finish?

Answer (score 5):

No, that's not a good pattern. async functions should have a callback parameter that you can use, and looking at the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate), there is one.

Make your function the second parameter to `setState`.

```
this.setState({...}, () => {
    this.props.somefunction(this.state.something);
}
```

The reason using `setTimeout` here is bad, is because you're taking a chance. You're saying, "I don't know how long this async operation will take, but I'm don't expect it to take longer than 100 ms, so I'm going to take a chance." But of course, you have no idea how long it will take.

The `callback` parameter ensures that the function will run after the async operation completes, so you don't need to cross your fingers.

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) recommends that you put your "callback logic" inside `componentDidUpdate()` instead of the seconds parameter of `setState()`.

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function
>   that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is
>   re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for
>   such logic instead.

Here's an example how to do this:

```
this.setState({
  something: this.state.something + 1
})

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.something !== prevState.something) {
    this.props.somefunction(this.state.something); // the state of something has changed -> execute callback function 
  }
}
```

Comment: can't I just use setState's callback? I don't have lifecycle method in my functional children component

Comment: Sure you can, there are always multiple ways to solve a problem. This example is just the recommended way from the React team.

Answer (score 0):

Using setTimeout to run actions on action complete is generally bad practice and the devs at facebook definitely took that into consideration. Which is why they have a callback method as the second argument for setState.

```
setState({ something: newState }, () => {
   // Run dependant actions here
})
```